# Error when switching from H2 in memory database to SQL Server

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

My project has this requirement where a user places a CSV file in a shared location which has to be pushed to SQL Server database. All the tutorials which I came across just use an in-memory database with hard-coded CSV file like below

https://github.com/TechPrimers/spring-batch-example-1

I was able to run the application successfully to load CSV into the DB with a few changes to the resource path.

> http://localhost:8081/load - Trigger point for Spring Batch.
>   http://localhost:8081/h2-console - H2 Console for querying the in-memory tables.

**I have a couple of general questions about how to make this run for our requirement:**

As I know in-memory will auto-configure a `DataSource` similar to what we see below: **What is the significance of `org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect`?**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

Replaced with below sql server configurations:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=springbootdb
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=Projects@123    
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

replaced the H2 database jar withSQL Server: `com.microsoft.sqlserver mssql-jdbc` `6.1.0.jre8` `test`

I am not sure about the significance of JPA while switching from in-memory to other Datasource(SQL server)? Here is below error which we are getting while changing its `DataSource` from in-memory DB to SQL Server, help here will be appreciated.

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-09-02 23:25:50.822 ERROR 6360 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'inMemoryDatabaseShutdownExecutor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/devtools/autoconfigure/DevToolsDataSourceAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'inMemoryDatabaseShutdownExecutor' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1181) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1075) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:297) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1080) ~[spring-context-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857) ~[spring-context-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.14.RELEASE.jar:1.5.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.14.RELEASE.jar:1.5.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.14.RELEASE.jar:1.5.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.14.RELEASE.jar:1.5.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.14.RELEASE.jar:1.5.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.14.RELEASE.jar:1.5.14.RELEASE]
    at com.techprimers.springbatchexample1.SpringBatchExample1Application.main(SpringBatchExample1Application.java:10) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.5.14.RELEASE.jar:1.5.14.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1181) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1075) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    ... 39 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

Answer (score 2):

> **What is the significance of `org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect`?**

JPA implementations like Hibernate need to generate SQL. 
The details how this SQL looks like are database dependent.
The `Dialect` encapsulates these differences.
So specifying `org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect` tells Hibernate to generate SQL suitable for an H2 database.

This should be unrelated to you current problem.

**As to the exception you are getting**

The root cause of the exception is:
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver`

Which most likely means the mentioned class is not on the classpath.

You described the dependency you are using as

`com.microsoft.sqlserver mssql-jdbc 6.1.0.jre8 test`

I assume this supposed to mean this snippet in your `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.0.jre8</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

If this is the case you are adding the driver only to the test scope. 
I.e. it will only be available for tests.
But you seem to try to actually start your application, not just running some tests.
Therefore removing the line `<scope>test</scope>` should fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added below dependency in `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
     <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
     <version>4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Please refer this for more info : https://springframework.guru/configuring-spring-boot-for-microsoft-sql-server/

Comment: Ok, updated the question with correcting the typo. thanks

Comment: Thanks, We tried all these there is no lunck, As I posted in the post we are using mssql-jdbc 6.1.0., Its working fine for one of our project. Did you tried the above code base or gussing the answers?

Comment: Adding jar manually in a maven project may be risky as there are chances of conflict and all..and I tried these things before and it works in the attached link.